Vaadin Flow format text in MessageList component
The text displayed in the MessageList component https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/message-list can contain basic formatting, for example
**System Accuracy**: Our algorithms are designed to perform searches almost instantly, providing you with accurate.' 

How can I configure the MessageList component to take this formatting (like **text**) into account and display the text accordingly, for example in bold?

Are you asking how to add formatted HTML? Or are you asking how to convert markdown to HTML with Java?

about how to add formatted HTML in MessageListItem
